# Rails: Turbolinks remove event listener after DOM change

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-events, turbolinks

How to know which part of the DOM has been replaced by Turbolink call?

Example flow:

1. On page load add event listener to few DOM nodes
2. Click on some link (Turbolinks will replace part of the DOM)
3. *Remove event listeners from DOM nodes that are replaced via
   Turbolinks*

In the documentation I found `page` events I can subscribe to, for example:

```
$(document).on('page:receive', function (e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

Sure I can tell from this that part of the DOM is about to be replaced, but how I can tell which part of it?

Comment: I thought that turbolinks replaced the body tag, but it's been a long time since my last full stack Rails app